# Is there any polytime reduction from feedback vertex set to vertex cover?

Tags: graphs, polynomial-time-reductions, vertex-cover

I know that feedback vertex set (FVS) problem is $\mathrm{NP}$-complete since there is a simple and nice polytime reduction from vertex cover (VC) problem to FVS.

Specifically, given a undirected graph $G$, we construct $G'$ as follow:

1. For every $uv \in E(G)$, we construct a new vertex $e_{uv}$, and let $V_{0} = \{ e_{uv} : uv \in E(G) \}$.
2. Let $V(G') = V(G) \cup V_{0}$
3. All the edges in $E(G)$ are in $E(G')$. As for $e_{uv} \in V_{0}$, $u,v$ are two endpoints of it, the two edges $ue_{uv}, ve_{uv}$ are both in $E(G')$. Namely, $E(G') = E(G) \cup \{ ue_{uv}, ve_{uv} : e_{uv} \in V_{0} \}$.

It is easy to see that $G$ has a vertex cover of size at most $k$ iff $G'$ has a feedback vertex set of size at most $k$. Namely, $FVS(G') = VC(G)$.

Of course, there is a polytime reduction from FVS to VC. I want to know whether there is a reduction with a simple construction. And I hope that the size of the vertex cover and the size of feedback vertex set are equalent, if possible.

Formally, assume there is a polytime reduction $\mathcal{A}$ from FVS to VC, and $G'$ is an instance of the FVS problem, $G = \mathcal{A}(G')$.
Suppose $$VC(\mathcal{A}(G')) = VC(G) = f(FVS(G'))$$
I want that $f$ is as small as possible.

Any related result is helpful. Let $k = FVS(G')$, it is unlike that $f = O(k)$, what about $O(k^2)$ or $O(k \log k)$? What if we restrict the the graph is planar (Note that the reduction from VC to FVS works for the planar version)?

Comment: For those who want complete reasoning for the reduction from VC to FVS: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709995/feedback-vertex-set-np-complete-proof

Comment: I had the idea of finding a [cycle basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_basis) (this can be done in poly-time) and then looking for a covering of cycles in the basis by vertices (this Set Cover problem can be straightforwardly encoded inside VC). But this doesn't work in general: Even though this will kill every basis cycle, and *every* cycle is a mod-2 "sum" of edges in basis cycles, it could be that there is a non-basis cycle all of whose basis components are hit at vertices that are not part of the sum, and this non-basis cycle will survive.

Comment: E.g.: The 9-vertex "window" (2x2 grid) graph has a (minimum-weight) cycle basis consisting of the 4 "panes". All of these cycles share the central vertex, so the above construction would incorrectly report a FVS solution of size 1 consisting of just that vertex -- even though this does not destroy the "boundary" cycle of the window, which consists of the mod-2 sum of all 4 panes. (In this case, some other cycle bases work -- but will this always be the case, and how to characterise them?)